# Integrate the ratio of quadratic forms

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, multivariable-calculus, quadratic-forms

Please, help me to solve the folowing problem.

Given two positive-definite $n$-dimensional matrices $A$ and $B$,
need to integrate its ratio over unit ball:
$\displaystyle\int\limits_{\|x\|\le1}\frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}Bx}dx$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they also symmetric?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang positive-definite matrices are symmetric by definition

Comment: All I can think to suggest is to change coordinates, making $x^\top Bx=y^\top y$, and then diagonalize the quadratic form $x^\top Ax$ in the $y$-coordinates. But, sadly, you're left with something like $\int_E \sum\lambda_j z_j^2\,dz$ where $E$ is a solid ellipsoid in $z$-space.